# web-scraping and pagination with python, csv, beautifulsoup and Pandas

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

This website **https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/** DB begins from year 1902 to 2022.  The code presented here captures some years for misses some as well.  The years before 1912 and the year after 2021 are not captured. I want to scrape **All Accidents for each type of aircraft** for **all** or **by year(s)**.  This **webDB** starts from **https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year=1902** and should end on **https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year=2022**.  Currently, the code dumps the results in **.csv** file, but it could also be in SQLite.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import re
import concurrent.futures

def scrape_year(year):
    # use a default looking header to cover my tracks in case they block requests that don't have "accept" and "user-agent" which sometimes happens
    headers =   {
        'accept':'*/*',
        'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
        }

    url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page=1'
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')

    page_container = soup.find('div',{'class':'pagenumbers'})
    pages = max([int(page['href'].split('=')[-1]) for page in  page_container.find_all('a')])   # get the maximum number of pages using "list comprehension", I get all the links at the bottom of the page ('a' tags) and the get the [href] for each, but split it on "=" making each a list, then get the last one ([-1]) and turn the text into an integer so I can get the max of all the integers ie the last page number

    info = []
    for page in range(1,pages+1):

        new_url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page={page}'
        print(new_url)

        data = requests.get(new_url,headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')


        table = soup.find('table',{'class':'hp'})


        regex = re.compile('list.*')
        for index,row in enumerate(table.find_all('tr',{'class':regex})):
            if index == 0:
                continue

            acc_link = 'https://aviation-safety.net/'+row.find('a')['href']
            try:
                acc_date = datetime.strptime(row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    acc_date = datetime.strptime("01"+row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        acc_date = datetime.strptime("01-01"+row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    except ValueError:
                        continue

            acc_type = row.find_all('td')[1].text
            acc_reg = row.find_all('td')[2].text
            acc_operator = row.find_all('td')[3].text
            acc_fat = row.find_all('td')[4].text
            acc_location = row.find_all('td')[5].text
            acc_dmg = row.find_all('td')[7].text

            item = {
                'acc_link' : acc_link,
                'acc_date': acc_date,
                'acc_type': acc_type,
                'acc_reg': acc_reg,
                'acc_operator' :acc_operator,
                'acc_fat':acc_fat,
                'acc_location':acc_location,
                'acc_dmg':acc_dmg
                }

            info.append(item)

    df= pd.DataFrame(info)
    df.to_csv(f'{year}_aviation-safety.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig', index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    START = 1901
    STOP = 2023

    years = [year for year in range(START,STOP+1)]

    print(f'Scraping {len(years)} years of data')

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60) as executor:
            final_list = executor.map(scrape_year,years)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lmao, I wrote that code for someone on this site once before. I've edited to work for the missing years here:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import re
import concurrent.futures

def scrape_year(year):

    try:
        headers =   {
            'accept':'*/*',
            'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
            }

        url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page=1'
        req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')

        page_container = soup.find('div',{'class':'pagenumbers'})

        try:
            pages = max([int(page['href'].split('=')[-1]) for page in  page_container.find_all('a')])
        except:
            pages = 1

        info = []
        for page in range(1,pages+1):

            new_url = f'https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year={year}&sorteer=datekey&page={page}'
            print(new_url)

            data = requests.get(new_url,headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')


            table = soup.find('table',{'class':'hp'})


            regex = re.compile('list.*')
            for row in table.find_all('tr',{'class':regex}):

                acc_link = 'https://aviation-safety.net/'+row.find('a')['href']
                try:
                    acc_date = datetime.strptime(row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        acc_date = datetime.strptime("01"+row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    except ValueError:
                        try:
                            acc_date = datetime.strptime("01-01"+row.find('a').text.strip(),'%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                        except ValueError:
                            continue

                acc_type = row.find_all('td')[1].text
                acc_reg = row.find_all('td')[2].text
                acc_operator = row.find_all('td')[3].text
                acc_fat = row.find_all('td')[4].text
                acc_location = row.find_all('td')[5].text
                acc_dmg = row.find_all('td')[7].text

                item = {
                    'acc_link' : acc_link,
                    'acc_date': acc_date,
                    'acc_type': acc_type,
                    'acc_reg': acc_reg,
                    'acc_operator' :acc_operator,
                    'acc_fat':acc_fat,
                    'acc_location':acc_location,
                    'acc_dmg':acc_dmg
                    }

                info.append(item)

        return info

    except Exception as e:
        print(e, url)
        return []


if __name__ == "__main__":

    START = 2022
    STOP = 2023

    years = [year for year in range(START,STOP+1)]

    print(f'Scraping {len(years)} years of data')

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=60) as executor:
        final_list = executor.map(scrape_year,years)

    list_of_dicts= list(final_list)
    flat_list = [item for sublist in list_of_dicts for item in sublist] #convert list of lists into one big list

    df= pd.DataFrame(flat_list)
    df.to_csv('all_years_aviation-safety.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: Dear bushcat69, I reposted this has a new question because I could not see the answer on **questions/70655467**  I thank you for the Try except inclusion in your reply above.  Safe weekend ahead. j

Comment: If I may ask, would having have all records dump in one single .csv file be possible as well?

Comment: Sure thing, I've edited the response above

Comment: I like this a lot.  Looking up close **https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/dblist.php?Year=1902** has 4 records.  For the year 1902, the all_years_aviation-safety.csv generates 3.   In all there are about 20k records that disappeared after run the code.  Can this be fixed?

Comment: Dear bushcat69, It appear that the problem lies within the 1st record of every given year. For example, the first record of each year is systematically not captured.  In our case the missing record begins with "href" the "all_years_aviation-safety.csv" file. Would picking these missing records with the code possible to do? Thank you.

Comment: Fixed again, for some reason I was skipping row 1, think I thought I was skipping the headers. Made the edit in the post above again

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I'll give it a run and will revert.  Pleasant evening!

Comment: Apologies for the delay in my reply, the output seem in good order.  With thanks and best regards.